# Emailing All Persons in a Sharepoint List Person Column

Tags: list, send-email, person-or-group, list-column

Hoping someone can help here. I'm new to SharePoint and just finding my way.

Within a Sharepoint list I have a person column named 'Initiative Leads'.

I want the end user to be able to click on an entry in the list and it sends a single email to the relevant 'Initiative Leads'.

Is that even possible?

I guess it might be if it's possible to build a calculated column that concatenates all of the email addresses from the person/persons named in 'Initiative Leads'?

Comment: If you're using SharePoint online, user can run Power Automate (Flow) on a **Selected** item to send email to the people defined in the *Initiative Leads* column. You could also use SharePoint designer workflows to send email.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? SharePoint online or SharePoint server?

Comment: Assume it's Sharepoint Online (it's part of our corporate Office 365 licence) it comes with Flow.   To be clear, I don't want to automate sending a mail when the 'Initiative Leads' field is updated, I want the end users of the site to be able to browse through the entries in the list and then click a list entry and have it send a mail to the Initiative Leads for that particular entry on the list.   Is it possible to invoke a flow in that manner?

Comment: @Graeme Johnson:   Do not use SP 2013 designer workflows. They will be deprecated in less than two years.

Answer (score 0):

@Graeme Johnson:
I’m going only with what you put in your question and comment.

With Microsoft Flow / Power Automate, you could create a ‘button flow’ that is triggered by a user on a page whereby you have both the button for the flow (and, optionally, maybe also a view of the actual list itself)

The flow would follow something approximating the logic below:

1. On button click [this is the trigger],
2. Initialize a variable of type Array,
3. Then iterate over each item in the list using the ‘[apply to each](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/apply-to-each)’ action and at the end of each iteration (within the same loop) add an ‘[append to array variable](https://flowaltdelete.ca/tag/append-array/)’.
4. After the first loop, create another ‘apply to each’ action (loop) and add an Outlook ‘[send an email](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#send-an-email-(v2))’ action, for each email in the array, an email, that you configure in the ‘send an email’ action, is sent to each email address in the array.

The flow will naturally terminate after sending the last email.  *Note:  this does **not** ensure deliverability of the email, just that it was sent.*

**Please up-vote if this helped you!**